# Where is the new Roslyn CompletionItem class Kept

Tags: c#, roslyn

I have recently been looking at some old Roslyn samples that use the `CompletionItem` class. However, in the new release the namespaces have changed, and I can't locate the appropriate namespace for this class. It was in `Roslyn.Services` but this is depreciated...

Where is the `CompletionItem` class and how can I access it?

Comment: Maybe [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/b93d401f-77ab-4793-bf8b-e5897ce0513f/roslyn-statement-completion-service?forum=roslyn) can clarify things. Seems like they removed it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It isn't currently public in the Visual Studio "14" CTPs, though we hope to add back the ability to contribute completion items at some point.

Comment: This is a pretty 'high level question', but I assume that I can still create intellisense for my editor using Roslyn without these classes or will I have to go to NRefactory?

Comment: You can get the set of symbols (but not keywords, snippets, etc) from the Workspaces layer using `Recommender.GetRecommendedSymbols`

Comment: So intellisense using Roslyn is no longer an option? Out of interest, why was this taken out, it was awesome. Thanks for your time...

Comment: You can build a large part of IntelliSense with the Recommender API mentioned above.  The complete API was removed because it encapsulated a lot of the *behavior* of IntelliSense, and we wanted the APIs to be more about the *data* behind them.  We weren't sure committing to an API that defined so much of the behavior would be the right thing for external hosts of IntelliSense.

Comment: @Kevin Pilch-Bisson, Wouldn't be true that Microsoft removed CompletionItem class for marketing reason. Having let both: "Recommender API" and "CompletionItem" class would have helped more people. IT appear to me that CompletionItem class was too close from VS editor and let people do create their own editor too easily? Microsoft was afraid and removed nice and easy to use code... so sad!